# How to I have an activity diagram with a continue statement in PlantUML

Tags: uml, plantuml, activity-diagram

Given the following PlantUML code:

```
@startuml

start

repeat
    :Task 1;

    if (Condition 1) then (Yes)
        :Task 2;
        
    else (No)
        :Continue Loop;
    endif


    if (Condition 2) then (Yes)
        :Task 3;
        
    else (No)
        :Continue Loop;
    endif
    
repeat while (More Data?) is (Yes) not (No)

end
@enduml
```

What I want is to have a loop continue where there is currently a task called Continue Loop. I can't see how this is possible.

Can someone please tell me what the syntax is for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

> What I want is to have a loop continue where there is currently a task called Continue Loop. I can't see how this is possible.

As Axel Kemper points out in his answer, there is no `continue` statement.

Like Axel, I refactored your if/then logic to nest the second condition inside the true result of the first condition. This makes it so that the `continue` instructions essentially fall through (false conditions) to the bottom of the loop. It's a solution to the example you gave, but it might not work for all cases of where you'd want to use a `continue`, like in Python or other languages:

```
@startuml

start

repeat
    :Task 1;

    if (Condition 1) then (Yes)
        :Task 2;

        if (Condition 2) then (Yes)
            :Task 3;
        else (No)
            ' :Continue Loop;
        endif        

    else (No)
        ' :Continue Loop;
    endif

repeat while (More Data?) is (Yes) not (No)

stop
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: See my comment at Axel's answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [PlantUML Reference Guide](https://plantuml.com/guide), no special `continue` command is available.
But there is a `backward` statement:

```
@startuml

start

repeat
    :Task 1;

    if (Condition 1) then (Yes)
        :Task 2;
        if (Condition 2) then (Yes)
            :Task 3;        
        endif       
    endif
backward: Continue Loop;
repeat while (More Data?) is (Yes) not (No)

end
@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: The hexagonal notation is not UML compliant. There is some compliance option for sure (not using it so often so I forgot its name).

Comment: The OP said the `Continue loop` is not really an action but something he want's to get rid of.

Comment: @qwerty_so `skinparam conditionStyle diamond` is the option, but I don't understand what this has to do with PlantUML (it's not a UML question, and the OP's diagram would also have the hexagons).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator It's a general observation. PlantUML is nice, but inventing it's own UML style (arrows and decision) is not. They should not carry UML as part of the name. Also I remember some `strict` parameter to render _correct_ arrows.

Comment: @qwerty_so `skinparam style strictuml` is maybe what you were thinking of? I agree PlantUML is non-standard, but as a diagramming tool it's pretty good and has likely made UML more popular over the years (I've been teaching UML for 20 years). I wish the OMG had looked at how UML was being used as much as PlantUML's dev does.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I agree in all you said :-)